# Is there any way to get back into a relationship with either Yen or Triss after they dump you?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Is there any way to get back into a relationship with either Yen or Triss after they dump you? I would go back to a previous save but it is hours before the event happened

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you're stuck like chuck. One they decide that there's no going back.

Comment: If you want people to like you, you need to be nice to them. If you are a dick you won't have many friends or lovers.